# How can i save or locally store a scanned qr code with dart flutter. does anyone have an idea?

Tags: flutter, dart

> How can i save or locally store a scanned qr code with dart flutter. does anyone have an idea ?
> i can scan the code already but i want to store it now. could you help me guys ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use shared preference to store data locally.
In your case, would store the scanning result in the share preferences.

See the package to see how to use it
https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of dart packages out there that you can use to store data locally.

**These are some of the packages:**

- [shared preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences): Simple key value based database.
- [hive](https://pub.dev/packages/hive): Document based database.
- [sqflite](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite): SQLite

*You can choose any of these based on your preference.*